# TableView edit method returns wrong row

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I want to create a new row in a tableview and open edit for it so the user can access it and write field values. I add the newly created element at the beginning of the table then I focus on the element and edit it. The focus works fine and selects the element correctly, but when I call the edit method it opens the edit for another element. Any suggestions?

```
//cellFactory for editing functionality for table cells

    Callback cellFactory
            = new Callback() {
        public TableCell call(TableColumn p) {
            return new EditingCell(tableCustomer);
        }
    };
```

```
//creating and adding the user to the table 

    Customer newRecord = new Customer(13, "test", "test", "test");
    tableCustomer.getItems().add(0, newRecord);
```

```
//focusing on the created element (at the beginning of the table)

    tableCustomer.requestFocus();
    tableCustomer.getSelectionModel().select(0);
    tableCustomer.getFocusModel().focus(0);
```

```
//attempting to open edit for the element returns a wrong element

    tableCustomer.edit(0, email);
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: try calling `TableView.layout()` first, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/52977437/1054140

Comment: @kleopatra, I made the issue in a minimal example, but unexpectedly it worked fine so I couldn't provide an example